# Filter By Size not showing all products under the filter in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The site I am facing an issue with is https://919kicks.com/product-category/sneakers/adidas/.

Here, if you try to filter by size on the left side and select one, then it works fine. But then if I select another filter (you'll notice the number of filters reduces and even vanishes) also the number of products remains the same as previous filter.

I thought initially its due to price filter min and max value, so I did a modification like:

```
    <form method="get" action="<?php echo esc_url( $form_action ); ?>">
    <div class="price_slider_wrapper">
        <div class="price_slider" style="display:none;"></div>
        <div class="price_slider_amount" data-step="<?php echo esc_attr( $step ); ?>">
            <input type="text" id="min_price" name="min_price" value="0" data-min="0" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr__( 'Min price', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
            <input type="text" id="max_price" name="max_price" value="50000" data-max="50000" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr__( 'Max price', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
            <?php /* translators: Filter: verb "to filter" */ ?>
            <button type="submit" class="button"><?php echo esc_html__( 'Filter', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
            <div class="price_label" style="display:none;">
                <?php echo esc_html__( 'Price:', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="from"></span> &mdash; <span class="to"></span>
            </div>
            <?php echo wc_query_string_form_fields( null, array( 'min_price', 'max_price', 'paged' ), '', true ); ?>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

If you notice in the form, I've changed the min_price value to 0 and the max_price value to 50000, but it does not work.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Everything seems to be working correctly on the site you linked. If you notice that some filters disappear it is most likely because the currently filtered products do not use those attributes.

Comment: @VincenzoDiGaetano Thank you for this! Next thing is why is it not showing the products when I select two filters? Like in this link: https://919kicks.com/product-category/sneakers/adidas/?filter_yeezy-slide-sizes=11us-46,8us-42

In this case, 3 products should be there, but only the last filter is working.

Comment: @VincenzoDiGaetano Still, like you said the filtered products don't use those attributes, what if I want to show all the attributes even if it doesn't use them.

Comment: I figured out a solution that is not a sure shot. It is selecting query type in the widget OR. But still after that, only 3 filters are working.